# Login Page shared preference not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I have an android app in which I am using shared preferences for login.Until now I have a flow like user logs in..when login is successful the credentials are stored.And when the user opens the app again the username password appears in the edit text.I have a login button and have setonclicklistner to login and jump to the inner activities.
I am trying a flow like when the user logs in successfully..and the app is restarted the credentials are stored..it should automatically go the next activity(inner activity).
What I have tried until now..

**In oncreate the onclicklistner that opens next activity if credentials are good**

```
buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(etemail.getText().toString().equals("") && etpass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter your username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    load_data();
                }

            }
        });
```

**Code of shared pref**

```
private void savePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    // Edit and commit
    UnameValue = etemail.getText().toString();
    PasswordValue = etpass.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(PREF_UNAME, UnameValue);
    editor.putString(PREF_PASSWORD, PasswordValue);
    editor.commit();
}

private void loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Get value
    UnameValue = settings.getString(PREF_UNAME, DefaultUnameValue);
    PasswordValue = settings.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, DefaultPasswordValue);

    etemail.setText(UnameValue);
    etpass.setText(PasswordValue);
}
```

What should I do in order to achieve this??if username password is stored automatically open next activity instead of clicking login button??
Thanks

Comment: Why using `SharedPreferences` and not `AccountManager`?

Comment: use SharedPreferences was in the ToDo given by my manager..:) nothing much I could do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `contains(String key)` in `SharedPreferences` class
could be done in `loadPreferences()`

if login is only used to allow access to the next activity, then you don't need to simulate the button click, but if the click loads other data based on the provided username/password then you have to do it using `performClick()` in Button class.

so your code may look like this:

```
private void loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(settings.contains(PREF_UNAME) && settings.contains(PREF_PASSWORD)){
        //you can start the 2nd activity directly here
        //Intent intent = new Intent (...)
        //startActivity(intent);
        //finish();

        //OR

        //load data into edittexts and programatically click the login button
        UnameValue = settings.getString(PREF_UNAME, DefaultUnameValue);
        PasswordValue = settings.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, DefaultPasswordValue);

        etemail.setText(UnameValue);
        etpass.setText(PasswordValue);

        //here it will click the button as if the user did it.
        btnLogin.performClick();
    }//contains
}
```

**Side note: it's not good practice (not secure) to store passwords in SharedPreferences specially plain-text, not encrypted**

Comment: Sounds useful..login button only opens next activity nothing else if credentials are good

Comment: @Akshay correct, came to my mind, that maybe even if the username/pwd are stored, you may want to check if they are correct, before starting next activity, to avoid any future bugs or so, ex, if you changed the password... so i think the better approach is to use `performClick()`

Comment: Also this is just a test app which will be used by max 4-5 people so no issues regarding storing credentials...anyways thanks mate got it working

Answer (score 0):

Open the next activity first, and then in `onCreate` method check if the user is logged in. If not close the first, and open the loggin activity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        CheckLogin();
... 
}
private void CheckLogin(){
        if(session.checkLogin()){finish();}
    }
```

**SessionManager.java**

```
  public boolean checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

            // Closing all the Activities from stack
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After storing username and password in sharedpreference `editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedin", true);`

So it should be like

```
    UnameValue = etemail.getText().toString();
    PasswordValue = etpass.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(PREF_UNAME, UnameValue);
    editor.putString(PREF_PASSWORD, PasswordValue);
    editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedin", true);
    editor.commit();
```

then check in Oncreate method like

```
    boolean hasLoggedin = sp.getBoolean("hasLoggedin", false);
            if (hasLoggedin) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
}
```